# How get all image in folder in my site to listview?

Tags: android, image, listview, lazylist

Hello everyone i using this [Lazylist](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) , i need this lazy read all image in one path.

example : 
i have this path `http://www.example.com/image`
in this path There are many image

> `http://www.example.com/image/image1.jpg`
>
> `http://www.example.com/image/sacimge.jpg`
>
> `http://www.example.com/image/xxx.jpg`
>
> and so on ...

need Lazy read all image in this path and insert in My Listview  why How do I do that ???

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible. There is no way for lazyList to know how many images you have and what are their url. I suggest you create webservice
like

```
http://www.example.com/image/cat
```

Returning a json or xml array containing all the urls of you images.
On server side you can access your image directory and build this list dynnamicaly.

Then in your app you can call this webservice using ([retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) lib to make it easy for you). Then you can feed this url list into your LazyList.